# Cassandra tunable consistency exercise

Tags: cassandra, consistency, bigdata, nosql

I need some help solving an exercise for school. It's about tunable consistency in Cassandra.

Given a cluster of 15 nodes, complete the following table. In case of multiple posibilities give all of them. CL values are: ANY, ONE, QUORUM, ALL

[image: Table of RF, CL, consistency and availability with blank cells]

Thank you very much for your help!

p.s. I'm sure that we need the following rule to solve this: nodes read + nodes written > replication factor to be consistent

Comment: That's awesome that you're learning Cassandra in school!  Which university are you at?

Comment: I'm studying at Ghent University in Belgium. The subject is called 'system design'.

Comment: This is very good to see a university studying Cassandra. For the record the most common consistency levels seen in production systems are `LOCAL_QUORUM`, `LOCAL_ONE` and `ONE`, with things like `QUORUM` and `ANY` less used. I've not seen the others used hardly at all, Having said that they all have their uses. Good luck with the studying!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should be the correct answer. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Ignore the dutch sentences in the table, I don't think it will pose any problems for english readers.

[image]

Comment: It is correct, Upvoted, but i know, you copied it. You shoud put some explanation, how you calculated these values. For Example Rule number 1 - To call a data consistent 
Write Consistency level + Read consistency level > Replication factor 
  
  
Rule number 2 - What is Quorum 
Replication Factor / 2 + 1 Rounded down - for example 7 /2 +1 = 4 (instead of 5)

Comment: As I stated below, link-only answers are not considered to be complete answers on SO.  If the link goes stale, then the answer is useless to anyone who finds it in the future.  Can you post the image in your answer?

Comment: @Aaron - I posted the image in my answer instead of the link.

Answer (score 4):

This document here should outline the consistency levels and how they function:

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlConfigConsistency.html

I've copied some of the content here for clarity if the link becomes broken in the future

> ## Write Consistency Levels
>
> **ALL**
>
> A write must be written to the commit log and memtable on all replica
>   nodes in the cluster for that partition.
>
> **EACH_QUORUM**      Strong consistency. A write must be written to the commit log and memtable on a quorum of replica nodes in each
>   datacenter.
>
> **QUORUM**
>
> A write must be written to the commit log and memtable on a quorum of
>   replica nodes across all datacenters.
>
> **LOCAL_QUORUM**
>
> Strong consistency. A write must be written to the commit log and
>   memtable on a quorum of replica nodes in the same datacenter as the
>   coordinator. Avoids latency of inter-datacenter communication.
>
> **ONE**
>
> A write must be written to the commit log and memtable of at least one
>   replica node.
>
> **TWO**      A write must be written to the commit log and memtable of at least two replica nodes.
>
> **THREE**       A write must be written to the commit log and memtable
>   of at least three replica nodes.
>
> **LOCAL_ONE**
>
> A write must be sent to, and successfully acknowledged by, at least
>   one replica node in the local datacenter.
>
> **ANY**
>
> A write must be written to at least one node. If all replica nodes for
>   the given partition key are down, the write can still succeed after a
>   hinted handoff has been written. If all replica nodes are down at
>   write time, an ANY write is not readable until the replica nodes for
>   that partition have recovered.
>
> ## Read consistency levels
>
> **ALL**
>
> Returns the record after all replicas have responded. The read
>   operation will fail if a replica does not respond. EACH_QUORUM
>
> Not supported for reads.
>
> **QUORUM**
>
> Returns the record after a quorum of replicas from all datacenters has
>   responded.
>
> **LOCAL_QUORUM**
>
> Returns the record after a quorum of replicas in the current
>   datacenter as the coordinator has reported. Avoids latency of
>   inter-datacenter communication.
>
> **ONE**
>
> Returns a response from the closest replica, as determined by the
>   snitch. By default, a read repair runs in the background to make the
>   other replicas consistent.
>
> **TWO**
>
> Returns the most recent data from two of the closest replicas.
>
> THREE
>
> Returns the most recent data from three of the closest replicas.
>
> **LOCAL_ONE**
>
> Returns a response from the closest replica in the local datacenter.
>
> **SERIAL**
>
> Allows reading the current (and possibly uncommitted) state of data
>   without proposing a new addition or update. If a SERIAL read finds an
>   uncommitted transaction in progress, it will commit the transaction as
>   part of the read. Similar to QUORUM.
>
> **LOCAL_SERIAL**
>
> Same as SERIAL, but confined to the datacenter.

Comment: Down voted for a link-only answer.  Please provide some of the relevant parts of the document here, in case the link should go stale (and I'll reverse my vote).

Comment: @Aaron - my mistake, good point. I've included the description explanations here as you say the link could break in the future, thanks for pointing that out